# how to display form with div correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this part of form field
[image]

When user click on the `Add` button will copy the above form field and user can add more in this field .

but when I add `<div id="ownership">` above the code form it start to look like this
[image]

I need to put `id=ownership` because I want to use it in my jQuery function

```
<div id="ownership">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30 ">
        <label for="add_owner"><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Name</b></label><br>
            <input class="from-control" type="text" id="name" >
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30" >
        <label for="add_owner"><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Phone number</b></label><br>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <input class="from-control" type="text"  id="phone" >
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30" >
        <label for="add_owner"><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Emailn</b></label><br>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <input class="from-control" type="email" id="email">
                </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="owner"></div>
<br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-30 add_info f-r">Add</button>      
</div>

<script>                                                  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add_info").click(function(){
        var newForm = $("#ownership").clone();
        $('input', newForm).val('');
         $('owner').append(newForm);
    });
    });
</script>
```

How do I fix the code in order to achieve the image in number 1 ?

Comment: Please add the relavent css aswell

Comment: Try adding `class="row"` so that it reads `<div id="ownership" class="row">`

Comment: Divide the row in bootstrap column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> Text</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> Text</div>
</div>
```

you need to apply this format then design will be properly according your desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Always use bootstrap col class inside row class then it will not cause unexpected result.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```